# utilizing spreadsheet find method in c#

Tags: c#, excel, string, winforms, ms-office

I made a C# winforms project which allows the user to pick a cell in a spreadsheet and write an integer value "total" into the selected cell. This takes place on an existing spreadsheet and thus this action changes the value of the cell. What is the best way to change some more cells with particular similarities?
My code is below:

```
 private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySheet = (Excel.Worksheet)MyBook.Sheets[1]; // Explicit cast is not required here
        bpRow = excelApp.ActiveCell.Row;
        bpColumn = excelApp.ActiveCell.Column;
        MySheet.Cells[bpRow, bpColumn] = total;
        Excel.Range colRangeH = MySheet.Columns["R:R"];//get the range object where you want to search from

        Excel.Range resultRangeH = colRangeH.Find(

            What: MySheet.Cells[bpRow, 18],

            LookIn: Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues,

            LookAt: Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,

            SearchOrder: Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,

            SearchDirection: Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext

            );
        textBox3.Text = "  " + resultRangeH;
        if (MySheet.Cells[resultRangeH, 16] == MySheet.Cells[bpRow, 16])
        {
            if (MySheet.Cells[resultRangeH, 22] == "T.PLATE")
                MySheet.Cells[resultRangeH, bpColumn] = 3 * MySheet.Cells[bpRow, bpColumn];
            else if (MySheet.Cells[resultRangeH, 22] == "STUD")
                MySheet.Cells[resultRangeH, bpColumn] = (int)(Math.Ceiling(MySheet.Cells[bpRow, bpColumn] / 1.33));
        }
        MyBook.Save();

    }
```

The spread sheet is made of about 90 entries and each row has a 21 numbers and a written description. I added a find method in my code to give me the row number of an entry with its 18th number equal to the 18th number in the entry corresponding to the selected cell. I then wrote a few if statements to check another number value and the written description. This is so that i may change the values in the column corresponding to the selected cell accordingly.

Comment: The code I used ends up displaying "COM_Object" in textBox3.

Comment: MySheet.Cells[bpRow, bpColumn].Value possibly?

Comment: I tried that, but there is still no change to other cells and textBox3 still displays "System_COMObject

Comment: `textBox3.Text = "  " + resultRangeH;` appends a range object to a string. in order to do that it's going to call `.ToString()` on the range object, which returns "COM_Object."  Try `textBox3.Text = "  " + resultRangeH.Text;`.